# How to import CSV data in R separated by tab/space?

Tags: r, csv

The data in have is as below in a .csv file.

id.airwaybill_number.order_number.org_pincode.product_type.inscan_date.pickup_date.actual_weight.original_act_weight.chargeable_weight.collectable_value.declared_value.code.name.active.center_shortcode.center_shortcode.if.sc.center_shortcode...NULL    csc.center_shortcode    sc.center_shortcode..rts_status.reverse_pickup.ref_airwaybill_number.dest_pincode.pincode.item_description.length.breadth.height.volumetric_weight.city_name.city_name.state_shortcode.state_shortcode.zone_shortcode.zone_shortcode

"61773384   147200492   SLP759809537    110008  ppd 2016-03-02 04:38:56 2016-03-01  0.25    0.25    0.5 0   424 92006   JASPER INFOTECH PRIVATE LIMITED activ   0   NULL    37.5    DLT MPS MPS 0   0   NULL    403516  403516  Vimarsh Rechargeable Tube With Charger Emergency Light  10  10  10  0.2 DELHI   MAPUSA  DL  GA  NCR WS"

When I import it into R using -

```
y <- read.csv("x.csv", sep = "\t")
y <- read.table("x.csv", sep = "\t")
```

All the data comes into one cell. This is sample of very big data and I want to import the data column wise and not in a single cell.

Please help.

Comment: So, the delimiter may not be tab. Try with `y <- read.table("x.csv")` or use `library(data.table);y1 <- fread("x.csv")` which will automatically pick up the delimiter

Comment: Is the second line in double quotes in your file?  The first line is not in double quotes.  Which other lines are in double quotes?

Comment: you can download a sample from [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8HvjRoyn_nQdTlZVlFwYTlidDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: fread("x.csv") is not solving the problem @akrun

Comment: @SushanG I can't connect to the link as I am in office.

Comment: have you tried `read.table` without the `sep=` argument? That breaks up your record by whitespace. I count 46 instances of whitespace in your sample record and 30 instances of underscore in the header. Shouldn't these be the same for your header fields to match the data in sample record?

Answer (score 2):

Your file is a little odd, in that it seems to have a mix of delimiters (some `\t`, some `_`, and some `,`), and as @Sun Bee mentions in the comments, your header doesn't seem to match up with your data. For those reasons, it might be worth working on the file "from scratch" rather than relying on something like `read.table` or `fread`.

First, read in the file as text:

```
con <- file( "x.csv" )
input <- readLines( con )
close( con )
```

Then perform a few tasks on it. First, split the text in each line by any of `\t`, `,`, and `_`.

```
data <- sapply( input, strsplit, "\t|,|_" )
```

If you take a look at the lengths of each element, you'll see that the first (the header) is an odd one out, meaning the values won't line up with the header names.

```
sapply( data, length )
```

My suggestion here is to remove that first row, and go without a header for now.

```
data <- data[ -1 ]
```

Then bind the list together rowwise to make a matrix* (which you can convert to a `data.frame` if you prefer). I'm removing the row names here because I assume you don't need them.

```
data <- do.call( rbind, data )
row.names(data) <- NULL
```

What results from the above is something that I'd say represents your data well, albeit without columns names. You can take the first line of your file and work with it to extract proper column names if you wish, but I'm not seeing exactly how they should go, so I won't attempt it here.

- NOTE if you want the `rbind` function not to convert the columns to `factor` class (which it will by default), you can specify `options( stringsAsFactors = FALSE )` beforehand.

Comment: @SushantG are you still interested in this? Has anything in the comments or my answer helped?